# TypeError: window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions is undefined ( Magento2 )

Tags: magento2

What could be missing from the payment method? Any Idea????

[image: On enabling custom payment gateway. some error like this is causing me to place the order.]

Comment: I guess the function getInstructions is not require, try remove this function from your file and check again

Comment: After removing getinstructions function this error occurs.

ReferenceError: getInstructions is not defined

magento2/pub/static/version1572335647/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/knockoutjs/knockout.js%20line%202982%20%3E%20Function

Comment: Oh great, the is fixed after I removed return within the function. this was because of the undefined window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];

Comment: That's good. :)

Comment: Why logins, form submission doesn't work well on chrome browser. but this is working fine on mozilla. what probably can be the solution to this.

Comment: Are you getting any error on console?

Comment: No console is clear

Comment: This is the error after i submit form

Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Comment: Hi, Every time I update / comment this section. the error goes away. but after upgrade the code return to uncomment. 

 getInstructions: function () {
      // return window.checkoutConfig.payment.instructions[this.item.method];
            },